# generic return type based on a Type paramater in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class with a dictionary that maps `Type` keys to objects that implement some interface `IWhatever`.

I wish to create a generic function that gets a Type as input and returns the object mapped to that type in the dictionary.

Something like :

```
public T get<T>(Type type)
```

Where T is an instance of type and type implements `IWhatever`.

I don't want to return `Object` or even `Iwhatever` but objects of the given type. the type of the return objects can clearly be infered at compile time. so I assume it should be possible.

I have managed to do this in java:

```
public T get<T>(Class<T extends IWhatever> type) { // implementation }
```

Is there any way to achieve this in C# ? if not, why not and what alternatives would you suggest ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want:

```
public T Get<T>() where T : IWhatever { ... }
```

For more information, see [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

This is of course only useful when the client can provide the type argument easily at compile-time. Internally, your method may need a lot of nastiness, e.g.:

```
return (T) myDict[typeof(T)];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'd love to know how the compiler is able to deduce the correct return type of a call to `get` as you've written it..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being misled by Java's erasure. Consider the following Java code from your post (edited to make it valid code):

```
public <T extends IWhatever> T get(Class<T> type) { // implementation }
```

In this case, the `type` parameter is only required because the generic type information is only available at compile time. This is not true in C#, where you can write the following:

```
public T Get<T>()
    where T : IWhatever
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    // rest of implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your first two sentences, what you want I think is the following.  You have to decide on some attribute of your types that will be unique.  You could make sure that all the types you have include the GUID attribute.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private Dictionary<GUID, object> _myDictionary;
  public AddObject(object objectToAdd)
  {
      _myDictionary.Add(objectToAdd.GUID, objectToAdd);
  }
  public object GetObject(Type typeToGet)
  {
    return _myDictionary[typeToGet.GUID];
  }
}
```

If the dictionary needs to contain multiple objects of each type, then the dictionary values can be lists of objects.